# Is there a way to use the search option: All directories but it skips to the next folder after searching first layer of the folder

Tags: c#, search, directory

I have a very large folder with *multiple subdirectories* in it, the files that I want to find are only located in the *first layer* of those subdirectories, I have tried the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` but it takes too much time. Is there a way to for the function to not search the *entire* subdirectory but only the *first layer* of it?

I have tried using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` but it still takes up **too much time**.

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
   @"\\Computer1\", 
    "Application.exe", 
     SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *nested* query:

1. Enumerate *top directories* within `@"\\Computer1\"`
2. Enumerate *files* within these top directories:

**Code:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

var files = Directory
  .EnumerateDirectories( @"\\Computer1\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  .SelectMany(dir => Directory
     .EnumerateFiles(dir, "Application.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)); 

foreach (var file in files) {
...
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to enumerate files of 1st and 2nd levels, you can nest the query *once more*:

```
var files = Directory
  .EnumerateDirectories( @"\\Computer1\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  .SelectMany(dir => Directory
      // 1st level
     .EnumerateFiles(dir, "Application.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
      // 2nd level
     .Concat(Directory
       .EnumerateDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
       .SelectMany(subdir => Directory.EnumerateFiles(subdir, "Application.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))));
```

In *general case* we can implement

```
private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string root, int level) {
  int current = 0;

  Queue<string> agenda = new Queue<string>();

  agenda.Enqueue(root);

  while (current <= level) {
    var list = agenda.ToList();

    agenda.Clear();

    foreach (var dir in list) {
      if (current > 0)
        yield return dir;

      if (current < level)
        foreach (var subdir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
          agenda.Enqueue(subdir);
    }

    current += 1;
  }
}
```

An use it:

```
// All subdirectories, up and including 2nd level
var files = EnumerateDirectories(@"\\Computer1\", 2)
  .SelectMany(dir => Directory
     .EnumerateFiles(dir, "Application.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));

foreach (var file in files) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `"*"` is the default search pattern and `TopDirectoryOnly` is the default search option, so they don't have to be explicitly stated.

Comment: @Rufus L: you are quite right, I've put `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` explicitly to show the idea; both `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` and `"*"` can be skipped

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko How do I do it if I want to search the first and second subdirectory before it skips to the next folder?

Comment: @LeoX: Again, nested query, but one level more

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Thanks! This helped a lot.